# T-SQL how to add trailing zeros to a string varchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, digits, trailing

My number needs to be 8 digits long, however If its less than 8 digits long I need to add trailing zeros to the it.

- Example: 1234
- Desired result: 12340000

I tried this at first:

```
DECLARE @YourNumber VARCHAR(8)=1234567;
SELECT DISTINCT 
LEFT('00000000'+CAST(ISNULL(@YourNumber,0) AS VARCHAR),8)
```

However the result is: `00000000`

Comment: So is it 12340000 or 00001234?

Comment: What do you want to return if the number = 0 or the number is < 0???

Answer (score 2):

I have the same read as @Hogan +1.   I just tend to opt for `concat()`.  No need to test for nulls or even care if the value is a string or int

**Example**

```
Select IfInt = left(concat(1234  ,'00000000'),8)
      ,IfStr = left(concat('1234','00000000'),8)
      ,IfNull= left(concat(null  ,'00000000'),8)
```

**Results**

```
IfInt       IfStr       IfNull
12340000    12340000    00000000
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are asking for is actually what you want then try this:

```
DECLARE @YourNumber VARCHAR(8)='1234567';
SELECT DISTINCT 
LEFT(CAST(ISNULL(@YourNumber,0) AS VARCHAR)+'00000000',8)
```

Comment: This is a quote from the requirements : `Desired result: 12340000`  looks like the zeros are at the end to me @XavierJ

Comment: @XavierJ -- even the title of the question says trailing zeros -- Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: Whoops, I misread that

Answer (score 0):

Since you are starting with a "number" in a string (`DECLARE @YourNumber VARCHAR(8)=1234567;`) there is no need to use `cast`. You can simply add the required number of zeroes:

```
DECLARE @YourNumber VARCHAR(8)= '1234567'; -- Using a string rather than an   Int  literal.
select @YourNumber + Replicate( '0', 8 - Len( @YourNumber ) ) as PaddedString;
```

Aside: It is a best practice to always specify the length of strings, i.e. `CAST(ISNULL(@YourNumber,0) AS VARCHAR(8))`.

Answer (score -2):

All you have to do is move the "+ '00000000'" portion of the code to the right side of the Cast Function.

```
DECLARE @YourNumber VARCHAR(8)=1234567;
SELECT DISTINCT 
LEFT(CAST(ISNULL(@YourNumber,0) AS VARCHAR)+'00000000',8)
```

Resulting in final value of: 12345670

Comment: This won't work since 1234567 is not a varchar constant.  How exactly is this different than the answer I posted 20 mins ago?

Comment: It isn't I just did not see your answer, so I decided to post the solution myself.